# How shoud Fabric8 CD-Pipeline work on OpenShift (without ImageStreams)

Tags: openshift, fabric8

I'm struggling getting the F8 CD-Pipeline to work on OpenShift. I use a Jenkinsfile downloaded from the [F8 Jenkinsfile Library](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-jenkinsfile-library) for Maven builds with steps "CanaryReleaseAndStage". The stage deploy step there looks like the following:

```
stage('Rollout Staging') {
        kubernetesApply(environment: envStage)
}
```

I looked up the implementation of kubernetesApply() from the [Kubernetes Pipeline Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-pipeline-plugin/blob/master/devops-steps/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/pipeline/devops/ApplyStepExecution.java). If no file parameter is present in the call (like here) it applies the Kubernetes/OpenShift resources defined in file "target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/openshift.yml", which is generated upon build.

In this file (which is also uploaded as artifact to the nexus, so I can easily fetch it) there are three resources defined:

- A Service
- A Deployment config, containing a Docker image reference (without tag), also containing a ConfigChange trigger listening for an ImageStreamTag 'my-project:latest'
- A Route

... but no ImageStream. However on the build log I see that an image stream definition apparently got generated on a different file:

```
[INFO] F8: Found tag on ImageStream my-project tag: sha256:c15b56841387a7e0aea960020ccf2efb48f21bd4d12d826e2cd04a94f4d9d748
[INFO] F8: ImageStream my-project written to /home/jenkins/workspace/my-project-dir/target/my-project-is.yml
```

But I'm afraid that one never gets applied to Kubernetes. Hence there is no image stream in the staging project.

In this configuration the staging deployment cannot even deploy the pod. If I add an image stream manually to the staging project it deploys but is never updated when new builds occur.

I've updated to the newest fabric/jenkins image 2.2.331, but it also does not seem to work here.

My pom.xml (parts essential for f8 building):

```
<project ...>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.package</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject/artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <fabric8.mode>openshift</fabric8.mode>
    <fabric8.build.strategy>docker</fabric8.build.strategy>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.28</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>fabric8/my-project</name>
                        <build>
                            <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src</dockerFileDir>
                            <dockerFile>Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resource</goal>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

So I'd like to know:

- How is the CD pipeline supposed to work regarding updates to the staging deployments here?
- Why is this image stream definition created if it is not applied. Am I missing some configuration here maybe.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of seeing your pom.xml and full build? It sounds like you are using fabric8-maven-plugin right? Its doing a S2I binary build and generating an image stream? It just sounds like somethings going wrong and the generated image stream isn't being included in your target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/openshift.yml maybe?

I wonder if something is going wrong in the order of your maven goals or something (e.g. typically fabric8:resource is first, then fabric8:build which then adds the ImageStream into the generated YAML files)

Comment: pom.xml added. Yes, I'm using the F8 maven plugin. I don't use s2i but docker build strategy, but it creates a s2i builder pod nevertheless to build the  docker image. The full log is too long to add it here (even after removing all maven downloading stuff). Any special area of interest?